# Returning to start of loop C

Tags: c, loops, return

I want to return to the start of the loop and make the user enter another input.

This is what I have but I keep getting the error message repeating over and over again.

How would I return so the user can enter a argument

```
printf("Enter a option\n");
scanf("%d", &option);

while (option != 1 || option != 2 || option != 3 || option != 4)
{
    if (option == 1)
    {
        option1(...);
        break;
    }
    else if (option == 2)
    {
        option2(...);
        break;
    }
    else if (option == 3)
    {
        option3(...);
        break;
    }
    else if (option == 4)
    {
        option4(...);
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nPlease enter a correct option\n");
        continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: it already does this, the logic should be be while(scanf...!=0) { ... }

Comment: @remyabel that's a lot of text to explain what "or" means :|

Answer (score 4):

Just rearrange the logic, for example like:

```
do {
printf("Enter a option\n"); 
scanf("%d",&option);

if(option == 1){
    option1(...);
    break;
}

else if(option == 2){
    option2(...);
    break;
}                       

else if(option == 3){
    option3(...);
    break;
}

else if(option == 4){
    option4(...);
    break;
}

else{
    printf("\nPlease enter a correct option\n");
    continue;
}

}
while(true);
```

Now your code does the `scanf` only once and then iterates over the same result, instead you must read the value each time you begin the loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
int option;

while(1)
{
  printf("Enter a option\n");
  scanf("%d",&option);

  if(option == 1){
    printf("option1\n");
    break;
  }

  else if(option == 2){
    printf("option2\n");
    break;
  }

  else if(option == 3){
    printf("option3\n");
    break;
  }

  else if(option == 4){
    printf("option4\n");
    break;
  }

  else{
    printf("\nPlease enter a correct option\n");
    continue;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use a do..while with printf/scanf inside.

```
do {

   printf("Enter a option\n"); 
   scanf("%d",&option);

   your if/else statements here... 

} while(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

you should Change your loop to do while.

```
 do
        {
             printf("Enter a option\n"); 
            scanf("%d",&option);

            if(option == 1){
                option1(...);
            }

            else if(option == 2){
                option2(...);
            }                       

            else if(option == 3){
                option3(...);
            }

            else if(option == 4){
                option4(...);
            }


            else{
                printf("\nPlease enter a correct option\n");
                continue;
            }

        }while(option != 1 || option != 2 || option != 3 || option != 4);
```